# Unable to stream audio and play it with Plugin.Maui.Audio

Tags: c#, .net, audio, maui, audio-streaming

I'm creating a Maui .Net 7 application that can play audio files and works well for local files on Android and Windows using Plugin.Maui.Audio. For local files, the below code works correctly.

```
var player = AudioManager.Current.CreatePlayer(await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("audio_file_name.mp3"));
player.Play();
```

The problem is that I want to play audio files that will be hosted on a web server or some remote location. I've tested it by uploading a few test files to a personal web hosting account and linking directly to the file, finding a test audio file hosted elsewhere `https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba.mp3`, And also setup Azure Blob storage and tried playing audio from there. Still, no matter what I try, the audio file does not play. Nothing happens. No errors. I tried the below 2 ways of having a remotely hosted file play in the app. Even if I press play and wait minutes for it to start playing, nothing happens.

#1. Streaming directly from the remote source:

```
var player = AudioManager.Current.CreatePlayer("https://link/to/file.mp3");
player.Play();
```

#2 Downloading the file first and then playing it:

```
        public async Task DownloadFile(string url, string filePath)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }

        var localFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "file.mp3");
        await DownloadFile("https://link/to/file.mp3", localFilePath);
        var player = AudioManager.Current.CreatePlayer(localFilePath);
        player.Play();
```

Looking into Plaugin.Maui.Audio, It's supposed to be able to play a Stream as well and not just local files. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any suggestions for having this work correctly for a Maui application?

Comment: The Audio file has an ASCII Header.  Open the file with text editor like notepad and check the type of audio.  You may not have the correct driver loaded on machine to play the audio type.

Comment: I've been testing with mp3 and with aac. These files work perfectly fine if stored locally in the raw folder. I've also created some of these files in Audacity myself and they contain no metadata other than the file name. That's not the case for all of them. Just some that I've tested that also work correctly offline/locally.

Comment: There may then be a bug in the application. Applications are suppose to test the file type  using both extension and ASCII Header. When you stream you only have the ASCII header.  If the same file paly properly loaded into a file and not a stream than the app is not reading the ASCII header from the stream, or the server is not sending the file type.  I'm not sure but a stream is a http response and the HTTP Header should contain the type of audio instead of in a ASCII Header.  The media player should be able to play the media without a ASCII header by specifying type. Maybe the player is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's supposed to be able to play a Stream as well and not just local
> files.

In the source code of the IAudioManager it provide the method.

```
 IAudioPlayer CreatePlayer(Stream audioStream)
        {
            return new AudioPlayer(audioStream);
        }
```

but just as jdweng said that `Applications are suppose to test the file type using both extension and ASCII Header` I am not sure that the https response can be recognized as a stream.

Acturaly, you can use the [MediaElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement) to play the audio by using the HTTP and HTTPS URI schemes. Here is the code sample:

```
<toolkit:MediaElement Source="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
              ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True" />
```

This MediaElement belongs to the [.NET MAUI Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/).

Comment: Awesome. This works. I'll replace Plugin.Maui.Audio with the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit MediaElement. Thank you!